# What is the Big O of this naive solution?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

Here is a simple fucntion that takes in two input strings. It returns True if the second string is an anagram of the first.

```
def validAnagram(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return False

    str1_arr = [char for char in str1]
    str2_arr = [char for char in str2]

    for char in str1_arr:
        if char in str2_arr:
            str2_arr.remove(char)
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

I am learning to calculate the Big O of the programs I write. Is this function's runtime O(N<sup>2</sup>) or O(N<sup>3</sup>)?

I assume its O(N<sup>3</sup>) because the "if" condition also runs O(N). So its 3 nested O(N) operations, resulting in O(N<sup>3</sup>) runtime. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think this belongs in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: There's no reason to build `str1_arr`. `str1` is just as iterable in a `for` loop as it is in the list comprehension that defines `str1_arr`.

Comment: @chepner I realize the redundancy. Was more obsessed with calculating the runtime than actually writing clean code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `O(N^2)`. You have `O(N)` iterations, in which you perform an `O(N)` operation. This results in `O(N^2)` complexity overall.

I think what you got wrong is calculating this part to be `O(N^2)`, while it's actually `O(N)`:

```
    if char in str2_arr:
        str2_arr.remove(char)
```

because you have `O(N) + O(N)` here, which is still just `O(N)`.

Comment: Isn't the if condition also iterating over the array to check if the element exists?

Comment: Yes, and that's why it's `O(N)`. The if statement is `O(N)` + the remove operation is `O(N)`. `O(N) + O(N)` is still `O(N)`.

Comment: Since the two O(N) operations are nested, doesn't that make this part O(N^2)?

Comment: No, you should not look at it from the perspective of nestedness. With for loops you have a multiplicative effect because you are doing something N times. With an if statement, you are only doing it once.